# Wagtail modeltranslation doesn't work with DEBUG = False

Tags: django, wagtail, django-modeltranslation

I have a problem with absent redirection to the default language for the multilanguage wagtail site.
If I set `DEBUG = False` on production, I got `Internal server error`, because redirection to url with language postfix is absent. If `DEBUG = True` everything works fine.

I'm using `wagtail_modeltranslation`

https://progtribe.com/ - doesn't work
https://progtribe.com/uk - works

I use Wagtail, Gunicorn, Nginx

In my error logs I see only
[image]

This log from gunicorn:
[image]

If I set DEBUG = True then I get 302 status code and everything is works
[image]

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
    path('dj_admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a (redacted/sanitised) traceback from your server logs to help us understand what's going wrong during the 500, please?

Comment: Also, currently (an hour after you asked), /ua is also throwing a 500 Server Error for me

Comment: sorry, I have made mistake in second url. not /ua, /uk

Comment: The logs you posted don't show a traceback. Can you replicate this locally using DEBUG=False and show what runserver outputs?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue with delete 404.html and 500.html from the main templates folder.

Comment: If deleting 404.html / 500.html solves this, then it probably means those templates were throwing an error in the process of handling a 404/500 response - most likely, your base template is assuming the presence of variables such as `page` which aren't available in that situation.