# Wagtail not redirecting. 500 error instead of 404 when DEBUG = False

Tags: wagtail, django-i18n

The guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879245/wagtail-modeltranslation-doesnt-work-with-debug-false) already asked about this and solved it by deleting `500.html` and `404.html`.

Same for me, when `DEBUG` is `True` everything works as expected: Wagtail redirects `/` to `/en`, on non-existing pages it gives 404 and so on.

Now when `DEBUG` is `False` when accessing `/` it returns 500 error without any error (only `Internal Server Error: /`, and I have `LOGGING` enabled, logfile has no errors either). If I delete `500.html` and `404.html` everything works, which is strange...

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    # path('django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

    path('admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    path('search/', search_views.search, name='search'),
]


urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path("search/", search_views.search, name="search"),
    path("", include(wagtail_urls)),
)


if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    # Serve static and media files from development server
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In `MIDDLEWARE` there is `'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',`

Also I noticed that the issue is in `404.html`, when using django templates, `extends`, `block` etc. Redirects dont work, if `404.html` is plain html - redirects work...

In Wagtail's issues on github there is kind of similar issue - [#6587](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/6587). I have the same behavior when `DEBUG = False` - Wagtail works when accessing "exactly that URL", redirects won't work.

Deleting 404 and 500 error templates is not great in production. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest investigating exactly which template tags cause the 404.html template to fail. My guess is that when you're pulling in a base template with `{% extends %}`, your base template is assuming the presence of variables such as `page` which aren't available when producing a 404 response.

In Wagtail, redirects are handled by a middleware which is activated when the normal page serving process returns a 404. If an error happens in the process of generating that 404 response, then the middleware won't identify it as a 404, and so redirects won't happen.

Comment: Oh, that will be a long way determing :D. Thanks a lot!

Comment: is SELF variable available when rendering 404?

Comment: No. `self` and `page` are both set to the Wagtail page instance that's handling the request, but for a 404, there is no such page.

Comment: Oh, that's sad. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again! What was causing the error was [this](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/i18n.html#basic-example) exact segment of `base.html`. I wrapped it around with `{% if page %} {% endif %}` and everything is working now. I think this should be in the docs, because this was quite confusing! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Have opened a PR to fix this now... https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/6609